# How to fork/parallelize process in purrr::pmap

Tags: r, parallel-processing, tidyverse, purrr

I have the following code that does serial processing with [purr::pmap](http://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map2.html)

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(1)
params <- tribble(
  ~mean, ~sd, ~n,
  5,     1,  1,
  10,     5,  3,
  -3,    10,  5
)
params %>% 
  pmap(rnorm)
#> [[1]]
#> [1] 4.373546
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> [1] 10.918217  5.821857 17.976404
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> [1]   0.2950777 -11.2046838   1.8742905   4.3832471   2.7578135
```

How can I parallelize (fork) the process above so that it runs faster and produces identical result?

Here, I use `rnorm` for illustration purpose, in reality I have a function that does heavy duty work. It needs parallelizing.

I'm open to non-purrr (non-tidyverse) solution, as long as it produces identical result given the `rnorm` function and `params` as input.

Comment: Is your actual function deterministic? If not and reproducibility is required for randomness too, I see no way. The results in each iteration depend on RNG state after previous iteration. Unless there's a way to know RNG state in advance (as seems to be the case in your example), and hacking around `.Random.seed`... but it's going to be ugly

Comment: See chapter 6 of https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/parallel/doc/parallel.pdf

Comment: Can you provide a more realistic example? Is the number of parameters (`nrow(params)`) high or the number of simulations `n`?

Comment: @Aurèle: my actual function is deterministic. So in my OP the exact reproducibility is not strictly required.

Comment: You can always pass the seed value as an additional parameter, and `set.seed(...)` on each worker

Comment: Sure, I meant reproduce the sequential behavior in parallel.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In short: a "parallel `pmap()`", allowing a similar syntax to `pmap()`, could look like: `lift(mcmapply)()` or `lift(clusterMap)()`.

---

If you're not on Windows, you could:

```
library(parallel)

# forking

set.seed(1, "L'Ecuyer")
params %>% 
  lift(mcmapply, mc.cores = detectCores() - 1)(FUN = rnorm)

# [[1]]
# [1] 4.514604
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.7022156 0.8734875 5.0250478
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]   8.7704060  11.7217925 -12.8776289 -10.7466152   0.5177089
```

*Edit*

Here is a "cleaner" option, that should feel more like using `pmap`:

```
nc <- max(parallel::detectCores() - 1, 1L)

par_pmap <- function(.l, .f, ..., mc.cores = getOption("mc.cores", 2L)) {
  do.call(
    parallel::mcmapply, 
    c(.l, list(FUN = .f, MoreArgs = list(...), SIMPLIFY = FALSE, mc.cores = mc.cores))
  )
}

f <- function(n, mean, sd, ...) rnorm(n, mean, sd) 

params %>% 
  par_pmap(f, some_other_arg_to_f = "foo", mc.cores = nc)
```

---

If you're on Windows (or any other OS), you could:

```
library(parallel)

# (Parallel SOCKet cluster)

cl <- makeCluster(detectCores() - 1)

clusterSetRNGStream(cl, 1)
params %>% 
  lift(clusterMap, cl = cl)(fun = rnorm)

# [[1]]
# [1] 5.460811
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 7.573021 6.870994 5.633097
# 
# [[3]]
# [1] -21.595569 -21.253025 -12.949904  -4.817278  -7.650049

stopCluster(cl)
```

---

In case you're more inclined to use `foreach`, you could:

```
library(doParallel)

# (fork by default on my Linux machine, should PSOCK by default on Windows)

registerDoParallel(cores = detectCores() - 1)

set.seed(1, "L'Ecuyer")
lift(foreach)(params) %dopar%
  rnorm(n, mean, sd)

# [[1]]
# [1] 4.514604
# 
# [[2]]
# [1] 0.7022156 0.8734875 5.0250478
# 
# [[3]]
# [1]   8.7704060  11.7217925 -12.8776289 -10.7466152   0.5177089

stopImplicitCluster()
```

Comment: Thanks so much, I have another issue related to your approach. Would you mind look at it? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47625279/how-to-preserve-the-list-of-data-frame-form-after-using-parallel-apply